# OpenVPN multiple IP addresses

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on my Linux box and it's working fine. The server has a lot of IP addresses but it only uses one for all the clients (of course).

Is it possible to use multiple IP addresses (public) on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post this question on ServerFault, this post will get more eyeballs.

OpenVPN can listen on multiple IP addresses. The directive `local` sets the IP address(s) it listens on. Here is an excerpt from OpenVPN man page.

```
--local host
```

Local host name or IP address for bind. If specified, OpenVPN will bind to this address only. If unspecified, OpenVPN will bind to all interfaces.

Watch out if you have multiple public IP addresses on multiple interfaces. You may have to resort to some sort of port forwarding. Probably you should make OpenVPN listen on a single interface, preferably local interface and port forward traffic coming from various public IP's to this Interface.